# How can I update pivot table by ID using updateExistingPivot?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I want to update specific order_product rows when update an order.

In case I have multiple products that have the same id at the same order but with different colors and quantities.

`order_product` table

| id | order_id | product_id | color | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | red | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | blue | 1 |

I'm trying to use `updateExistingPivot()` but it updates the records like just the last one.

This is how the body I sent when updating order look like:

```
{
"products": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "color": "red",
        "quantity": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "color": "blue",
        "quantity": 3
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "color": "black",
        "quantity": 5
    }
]}
```

That's what I expected to see

| id | order_id | product_id | color | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | red | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | blue | 3 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | black | 5 |

Instead, got this

| id | order_id | product_id | color | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | blue | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | blue | 3 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | black | 5 |

`OrdersController`

```php
    public function update(AdminUpdateOrderRequest $request, $id)
    {
        $orderValidated = $request->validated();

        $order = Order::findOrFail($id);
        
        $order->update($orderValidated);

        foreach ($orderValidated['products'] as $product) {
            $order->products()->updateExistingPivot(
                $product['id'], [
                    'color' => $product['color'],
                    'quantity' => $product['quantity'],
                ]
            );
        }
        return OrderResource::make($order)->additional([
            'success' => true,
        ]);
    }
```

`OrderModel`

```php
public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class)->withPivot(['color', 'quantity', 'id'])->withTimestamps();
    }
```

Comment: Your `products` array has `id: 1` listed twice, and you also have `product_id: 1` in your DB twice; that shouldn't be able to happen in a `many-to-many`.

Comment: When you pass `id: 1` to `updateExistingPivot()`, it _is_ updating it, but since you have `order_id: 1 | product_id: 1` twice in your database, it doesn't know _which_ row to update. That should only be there once (maybe add a `unique` constraint to your database to handle this?)